# Digital Synagogue displays?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, synagogue

Why do Synagogues use or not use them?

Bonus:

What are some of the companies that make these digital wall displays for synagogues?

How much do they cost?

Does anyone know where I can find info online about them?

Feel free to add screenshots and pictures.

Comment: Moshe, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: @Isaac - Thanks. It's good to see SE sites springing up. (Especially a jewish one.) Perhaps it makes sense to try to get this site nominated at Area 51 for SE 2.

Comment: @Moshe, The transition to SE 2.0 is not that simple. See 
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/migration-of-se-1-0-sites/ . Right now, we have a guarantee that we can run m.y as a SE 1.0 site until at least April '11. It seems that at some point before then, we may be offered the chance to apply to migrate to SE 2.0 if we have enough traffic. Area 51 would be to create a new site, which would not have our existing community or content. There are some proposals for related sites there already (search for Jewish at http://area51.stackexchange.com/ ).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33900/759

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of a marketing question than a Judaism question. It might have fit once upon a time when the site was younger, but as it matured, I'm pretty sure it's off topic now.

Answer (score 8):

We have one of these in our Synagogue (based in the UK) and it was cheap and easy to set up. Here's some details on how we did it...

We have a large flat-screen TV (that can also operate as a computer monitor) on the wall. This was donated. On the other side of the wall is a regular, old Windows XP PC, with internet access. The PC runs internet explorer in full screen (kiosk mode) permanently looking at our own special website.

The website is built on Joomla, which is an open source content management system. The TV in the synagogue displays the front-end (public view) and we can use the administration view to edit the content from any internet connected computer.

We wrote some really simple Joomla components to display display static images (GIFs) and Flash Animations. When you upload each file to the system you can specify how long to display it for, dates for which it is valid etc.

We have ours in the foyer and it is primarily used to advertise events / announcements etc.

Comment: Matt, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for giving us the benefit of your experience! We'd love to have you as a fully registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking register, above.

Comment: How are Zmanim updated? Automatically, or manually?

Answer (score 5):

While it's not like the one that I've seen in shuls, the cheapest way of doing it would probably be to buy a decent sized screen (20"+ should be great and costs around $150 now) and hook it up to an old computer running this program: http://www.kaluach.com/?page_id=147 (which costs $225).  If you have someone with decent carpentry experience, you could make a coherent and presentable system for under $400.  I'm sure that this would be much cheaper than the typical shul device.

Comment: I saw that program. I'm not a fan of it. It looks way to clunky.

Comment: You're forgetting the computer too. Add at least 300 to that. Plus extension cables to hide the computer somewhere. And a mount. And finish to hide the cable.

Answer (score 4):

The toll free number to get one is 1-877-J-Calendar

Comment: Which company is that?

Comment: These guys have what I was thinking of. It's good to be able to find that online. Googling the number found the site.

Comment: http://www.beezeesystems.com/products-jcalendar.asp , in case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of any reason Shuls would not use them. [Unless they are a distraction?] Who said there are Shuls who don't use them? It's quite possible Shuls don't have them because of the cost. In every Shul I've seen them in, they were donated...

(I'm assuming you mean the displays that contain things like the date, parsha of the week, and selection of zmanim)

Comment: Exactly those. Btw, great to see you here. Can you find out pricing and vendor contact information?

Comment: Well in some of those Shuls, there was a phone number on the device (or near the device). Try calling it and asking...

Comment: Please post a number here if you can. Or message me on twitter. Or gmail. Or... ;D

Answer (score 3):

The Shtiblach Katamon shul in Jerusalem has the Shtibluach Electronic Luach for Synagogues. [www.shtibluach.com](http://www.shtibluach.com).

It's windows-based, can be configured to display any number of davening schedules and zmanim, popup messages, daf yomi, parsha, etc.

Comment: What does this cost?

Comment: Kesty, thanks for the recommendation and welcome to the site: I hope you stick around and enjoy it.

Comment: It costs around $500 for the software. It requires a screen (whatever size you decide) and a computer running Windows XP or above. It has a friendly user interface for configuring schedules, customs, pop-up messages and more.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to make an exception, and answer this question with a product of my own, since it's relevant.

I've written an app for iPad that does precisely this. It's called Gabbai, and I think that it's really the best that there is. [Gabbai for iPad](http://getgabbai.com) requires an iPad and a mount and that's it. It uses your GPS location to calculate zmanim on the fly, and it use the internet. You can customize zmanim to show text and pictures.

[Get Gabbai](http://getgabbai.com)

Answer (score 1):

luach nissan - http://www.zmaniayom.co.il/English/index_english.htm
Schedule today - digital computer board your synagogue.

Today, it's easy to lay all the necessary information in a synagogue praying the prayers of my time and my time Torah classes, times and changes in prayer today tocommemorate deceased and all computerized smart board,
Your synagogue!
Easy, resting and user-friendly.

Comment: Hi nissan and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Thank you for the link, but could you revise the text to sound less "marketing"-y?  Also, if you are affiliated with this product, that's fine but you [need to declare it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145583/162102).  Thanks, and I look forward to seeing you around the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try DigiZman.com 
The easiest, comprehensive and nicest graphical interface. They also have a corresponding app

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Jerry! How do you know they are the " easiest, comprehensive and nicest graphical interface"? Are you affiliated with the site? If so, you should note that. Consider learning more about the site from this [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Answer (score -3):

[Schedule today - digital computer board your synagogue](http://www.zmaniayom.co.il/English/index_english.htm)

Schedule today - digital computer board your synagogue.

Today, it's easy to lay all the necessary information in a synagogue praying the prayers of my time and my time Torah classes, times and changes in prayer today tocommemorate deceased and all computerized smart board,
Your synagogue!
Easy, resting and user-friendly.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product, a satisfied user, or something else?  (If the first, site rules require that you say so.  If the second, it would be helpful if you could go into more detail about how it met your needs.)  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it, because it's named "Luach Nissan", which is this user's first name.