# Shul Donations Kiosk

Tags: product-recommendation, synagogue, tzedakah-charity, phone

Where can I find information for a digital wall kiosk to hang up in a Shul to get donations or to pay Shul balances?

I saw that in Israel they have it in almost every shul but in the US I don't see it very often.

Comment: "I saw that in Israel they have it in almost every shul": I've never seen this, and I've been in about two dozen synagogues in Israel within the past few months. That doesn't invalidate your question, of course: it's still reasonable to ask where to find info such a thing. Can you [edit] you question, though, to clarify what kind of info you seek? Do you want to know how it works? where it's made? where you can buy one? something else?

Comment: @sabbahillel, are you thinking of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2773, perhaps?

Comment: @sabbahillel: That is for a zemanim display. This question is regarding a payment kiosk.

Comment: Ever been to Shomer Shabbos in Brooklyn, NY? They got these payment kiosks from a company called Charitybox or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

[ShulCloud](https://www.shulcloud.com/shul-kiosk) offers such a system.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen those in any Israeli shul but it is still a good idea. Some options include

- [iPushka](http://ipushka.net/) - interestingly they install the kiosks at zero charges and instead make money as a percentage of the payments
- [qGiv](https://www.qgiv.com/on-site-giving-kiosk)
- [GivingKiosk](http://www.givingkiosk.com/) - originally built for churches
- [easyTithe](https://www.easytithe.com/features.htm) - similarly, was originally built for churches
- [Karma Payments](https://karma-payments.myshopify.com/) - which advertises to the Jewish community specifically

You could also build your own low-cost kiosk by leveraging an old tablet with the [Square Reader](https://squareup.com/reader).

Note that with the prevalence of mobile technology, you might be well served by a mobile donation system. We are planning this for our shul in Israel leveraging Hapoalim's [bitpay](https://www.bitpay.co.il/) and Leumi's [Pepper Pay](http://www.pepper.co.il/en/products/pepper-pay/). The US equivalent would be [Venmo](https://venmo.com/) or [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/gb/home).

Comment: I've seen many such devices in Bnei Brak with which you could also charge your Rav Kav. Don't you have one at your place?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I saw some of them live at the offices of non profits but not in synagogues

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 popular ones in Israeli shuls (in no particular order):

1. [Nedarim Plus](https://www.matara.pro/nedarimplus/) 
    [image]
2. [Kehiloth](http://www.kesherhk.co.il/?page_id=2221) 
    [image]

Comment: I'd be reluctant to give through any service with "Nedarim" in its name...  I wonder why they chose that name.