# Digital Zmanim Displays from Bee Zee Systems

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, synagogue, zemanim

I noticed digital zmanim displays in many synagogues from Bee Zee Systems and I would like to get a break down of the cost associated with installing such a system.

I contacted Bee Zee Systems and I was told that such a system would cost about $4,000 however I was not able to get specific details about the cost - how much of the money goes towards hardware, how much goes towards software and is the software cost a recurring fee or a one time fee (assuming a 60 inch screen). When I tried getting in touch with them again they would not answer my question without making me jump through hoops.

If anyone can provide a detailed breakdown of the costs it would be enormously helpful.

Thanks

Note: For all those who think this is a duplicate of the other question please re-read both questions.

I am specifically asking for a breakdown of the cost of installing this product. I already know the general cost (in fact it's already in my question). The other question primarily wants to know which companies produce such systems. As far as the cost - it does not ask for a breakdown of costs. Moreover, there is no answer regarding the cost of this system at all (not in general and not a breakdown). Please re-open this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Judaism.

Comment: Why is it any different than https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/digital-synagogue-displays ?

Comment: You're right. It is very little different. I still think both questions are not about Judaism. But don't worry, your question will remain open if I am in a minority of one.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Did you choose to close that one too? It has 9 answers and over 1,000 views. Let's not be too nitpicky, please.

Comment: I see Avrohom's point. OTOH, there is some Judaism relevance as this board is used in many shuls. It doesn't seem much different as someone asking how much does Rabbi Ezra Sofer charge to write a new Sefer Torah for a shul?

Comment: Mr. Kevin - Why is this current question not a dupe of the other one that you linked to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Digital Synagogue displays?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/digital-synagogue-displays)

Comment: Although you are asking a narrower question, my reading of [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/closing-as-duplicate-of-broader-post) says that it is still a duplicate. Annoying for new users, to be sure (where you can't do things like start a bounty or whatever to get the detail that you are looking for), but that is the situation.

Comment: Technically this is both off-topic as AY said and a dupe as Yishai said, but I chose to break the tie as off-topic, as I felt that it's the more compelling reason to close the question. And yes, just because a question has 9 answers doesn't make it on-topic, and so I voted to close that one, too, at the time.